# href not working for nav-link collapsed class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, href

Href is not working when clicking category link. The menu is collapsed and it works for subcategories. The value is present in href but it collapses to subcategory.

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="www.google.com" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#id1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#id1"> --category
<div class="collapse" id = "#id1">
    <a class="nav-link" href="www.fb.com"></a> --subcategory1
    <a class="nav-link" href="www.twitter.com"></a> --subcategory2
</div>  
 </a>
```

I don't know which if i change any class name it it will affect sub  category(which is working fine).Please help.

Comment: your category label is not inside <a> tag. Isn't that the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I am not using my code. I just created a sample code for an explanation.There is no issue with the closing tag. @Thamindu DJ

Comment: You should provide the correct format for your questions. Otherwise people will be misguided. What I meant was, tags should be like this <a>--subcategory1</a>

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice that. I edited and changed the question. Thanks for that. But the issue still remains.Any idea? @ThaminduDJ

Comment: It's not the problem. In order to click on a tag and it to work, the labels should be within anchor tags. In your code, inner anchor tag labels are outside the tags (--subcategory1 and --subcategory2). Also, now you have included a div and two anchor tags inside another anchor tag. It doesn't make any sense

Comment: Also you should include the full url as mentioned in the below answer. For example instead of 'www.google.com' you should provide it with 'https://'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the entire URL. For example https://www.twitter.com/
Also, Your first anchor tag isn’t closing anywhere

Comment: I am using twitter as an example.  Actually the link is got from code(href='../account/MarketPlace.aspx?Category=" + productcategory.ProductCategory + "') @Jayg713

Comment: There is no issue with URL, it just that when clicking the category, the nav collapses and the href for category is not working.

Comment: Try closing the first anchor tag @themoonchild

Comment: I didn't notice that when I post the question,I changed it. Thanks. Any idea on how to solve my issue?